# Dropdown Save in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I have a GRID that consist of columns that are populated and recently I have added some drop down columns as well to the grid. My drop down is populating with the options from the backend, but now I need to save those answers to the page itself, so the user can see it on the screen next time they arrive on the page.

**GRID**

```
protected void gvViolationsCited_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {

        TableCell idCell = GridViewFunctions.FindCellByDataField(e.Row, "ID");
        idCell.Visible = false;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ImageButton lb = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbShowModalDialog");
            long id = long.Parse(idCell.Text);

             DropDownList hpvcriteria = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("hpvcriteria");
            hpvcriteria.DataSource = LookupDataLoaderService.Instance.LoadLookupData(LookupTables.HPV_VIOLATION_CODE);
            hpvcriteria.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

  private void PopulateViolationGrid(long caseID)
{
    IList<EnforcementViolation> enforcementViolations = LovService.Instance.GetEnforcementLovList(caseID);
    IEnumerator<EnforcementViolation> evEnumerator = enforcementViolations.GetEnumerator();
    while (evEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        EnforcementViolation ev = evEnumerator.Current;
        //txtOtherDocsViolated.Text += ev.Permit + " ";
    }
    gvViolationsCited.DataSource = GridViewFunctions.GenericListToDataTable<EnforcementViolation>(enforcementViolations);
    gvViolationsCited.DataBind();
    upnlViolationsCited.Update();
    evEnumerator.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: So you are not saving any user data as yet?  What have you tried to implement?

Comment: Data is saving if it isn't a dropdown but as soon as I change it to a drop down I am not able to save my drop down. I'm editing my question with the drop down code as well.

Comment: where is the code you use to Save the data?

Comment: This is a grid, and the dropdown is a new feature to it. So the dropdown automatically becomes a part of the gridview. So far I only have been populating only.

Comment: So you have no save routine?  Then what are you trying to accomplish?  making sure the dropdown lists retain their selected values after a postback?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Also saves the value in database as well. I have a get and update SP for it.

Comment: ok - then likely you are rebinding the gridview on every postback - there is no need to do that.  The only time you need to rebind is if the underlying data changes. Controls embedded within a GridView, like DropDownLists likewise do not need to be rebound unless the underlying list options have changed.  Doing so will cause the DDL to reset selected values.  As things stand you bind the DDL when you bind the GridView,  make sure you only bind the Gridview when necessary, typically this is done by wrapping the GridView DataBind() in an `if( !Page.IsPostback )`

Comment: so just remove the databind from the dropdown function?

Comment: No, you still need that, but as it's part of the RowDatabound event of the GridView you're OK there.  Where are calling `gvViolationsCited.DataBind()`

Comment: I edited my initial question, please check the populate violation grid method.

Comment: where is `PopulateViolationGrid()` called?

Comment: private void LoadControlValues(AutoCompleteItem autoCompleteItem)
    {

        if (autoCompleteItem.EnfCaseID > 0)
        {PopulateViolationGrid(autoCompleteItem.EnfCaseID);}

Comment: I personally thought I needed a selected item function for the value to store on the page, but I injected record at the backend yet it doesn't show at the front end.

Comment: a DDL renders to an HTML `select`.  So when you post the form back it's like any other input field.  the selected item on the page in just sent back with the rest of the page and the LifeCycle begins anew.  Controls load their state and then, if you're not careful about managing your binding process, you will reset the state of the controls to unselected

Comment: Just try wrapping your Gridview's DataBind in an`if( !Page.IsPostBack )`

Comment: you may or may not need to handle an OnSelectedItemChanged event for each DDL depending on how you want to process your page.  if you want to handle an update for each selected item as they change, then yes you have to enable the AutoPostback property of the DDL and hadle saves accordingly.  Or you can disable that property and have an "Save" button that is external to the gridview that batch processes the DDL for each gridview row and saves as needed

Comment: when you "injected a record at the backend" and expected to see that addition reflected in the GridView, ***this*** is when you need to make a call to the rebind the Gridviews.

Comment: Tried the binding in the postback and didn't work. Sorry getting a bit confused here now.

Comment: Then the best thing to do is go back to the basics.  Create a new test page and just add a simple gridview from a simple data source an add a simple DDL to each row that has say 2 hard coded choices.  and experiment.  see what you have to do to make sure the DDL retains it's state between postbacks.  Use some external button to trigger the postback

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ((Master_Site)this.Master).TopSectionLabel = "Case Information";
            ((Master_Site)this.Master).DetailedSectionLabel.Visible = false;
            ((Master_Site)this.Master).EnforcementHeader.Visible = true;
            LoadDropdownControls();
            if (GetAutoCompleteItem != null)
                LoadControlValues(GetAutoCompleteItem);
            base.SetPrincipalPolicy();

        }